# GTK3: Detect SHIFT was pressed during application start

Tags: gtk3, gdk

I'm writing a simple GTK3 application and I need to detect, that SHIFT key is pressed during while application is loading.

I want to quit as early as possible, if SHIFT is not pressed. So I have no application window at this point

How can I query global keyboard state from GTK/GDK?

I tried to use `gdk_seat_get_keyboard` + `gdk_window_get_device_position`, but I get `gdk_window_get_device_position_double: assertion 'gdk_device_get_source (device) != GDK_SOURCE_KEYBOARD' failed` in console. It also requires to have an application window.

I'm ok with code sample in any language (C, Vala, Python preferred)

Comment: Make your mainwindiw grab focus (gtk_widget_grab_focus(GTK_WIDGET(mainwindow)) connect to keypress signal and filter values (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58996897/8627962)

Comment: key press won't do the job as shift isn't a keypress. It only becomes a keypress event when you press another button say a in which case you can differentiate a from A.

Comment: This is OS level functionality and not really a GTK question. You could delay your application start a reasonable amount of time and use OS level queries to check if the shift key is depressed.